# I am not able to split the string in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have some sentences separated by a mixed case token, like :-

```
String s = "Hi, I am a cool Programmer.GO I love to code in Java language.Go Coding is fun for me.";
```

Now, I want to split these sentences on `"GO"` or `"Go"` (case doesn't matter here).

I am currently doing it like this :-

```
s.split("GO");
```

But that only splits on upper case.

Comment: Hint: String::split's argument is a regex.  See javadocs for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.split` takes a *regular expression*; the "easy" solution is to define two patterns. The first pattern to match capital and lower case "G", and the second to match both cases of "O". We also should remove any white-space before or after the pattern (the `\\s*` matches none or more white-space). And use `\\b` to force a boundary,

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("\\s*\\b[Gg][Oo]\\b\\s*")));
```

Outputs

```
[Hi, I am a cool Programmer., I love to code in Java language., Coding is fun for me.]
```

Another option is the `(?i)` case-insensitve flag. Like,

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split((?i)\\s*\\bGO\\b\\s*)));
```

For the same result.

Comment: Man, when the string having word like Goa , regex is splitting this also.

Comment: I got that solution, regex be like:-    ```String splitRegex = "\\s*[Gg][Oo][ ]\\s*";```

Comment: @Rockers Edited. I would prefer a boundary. There is no need to put space in a pattern `[ ]`.